Export CatBoost json without saving to a file
I am trying to export CatBoost model object to json directly, without saving to a file.
Following this Tutorial,
import json

...

cls.save_model(
    "model.json",
    format="json",
    categorical features.
)

model = json.load(open("model.json", "r"))

At this stage we got json (not CatBoostClassifier) in model object after these steps.
Is there any way to get exact json by some method call maybe?
